# Find entries of a column in a database in all entries of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, postgresql

Consider the following schema for a database modeling courses:

DEPARTMENT (did, name),

COURSE (cid, did, name, num, creditHours),

STUDENT (sid, fname, lname, did)

ENROLLED_IN (eid, sid, cid)

**List the first and last names of all students enrolled in every COMP course (DEPARTMENT.name="COMP")**

Comment: SELECT fname, lname
FROM COURSE, STUDENT, ENROLLED_IN
WHERE STUDENT.sid = ENROLLED_IN.sid
AND ENROLLED_IN.cid = COURSE.cid;

Comment: Do you only need to list the names of students that are enrolled in EVERY COMP course (i.e. students that are not enrolled in each and every COMP course would be omitted) or are you looking for the names of students that are enrolled in ANY COMP course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a GROUP BY with a HAVING clause to assert the number of COMP courses enrolled in:

```
SELECT s.fname, s.lname
FROM STUDENT s
JOIN ENROLLED_IN e ON s.sid = e.sid
JOIN COURSE c ON e.cid = c.cid
JOIN DEPARTMENT d ON c.did = d.did
WHERE d.name = 'COMP'
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM COURSE c
    JOIN DEPARTMENT d ON c.did = d.did
    WHERE d.name = 'COMP')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with join

```
SELECT s.* FROM STUDENT s
JOIN ENROLLED_IN e ON (s.sid = e.sid)
JOIN DEPARTMENT d ON(s.did = d.did)
JOIN COURSE c ON(d.did = c.did)
WHERE d.name="COMP"
```

Comment: this gives the students enrolled in any COMP courses, not every COMP course